# Receive SMS/Alert when specified text detected in a log file

Tags: 18.04, notification, monitoring, sms

I've been searching for a service for Linux that monitors logs for a certain text string and if that string matches, it sends a notification, ideally by SMS.

If the log text file contains "SPECIFIED TEXT", it calls this API...

A Telegram bot could also work...

Regardless if this service is paid or not, SMS would be preferred.

Thank you!

Comment: There's no such service AFAIK but a script could theoretically do that. How it would interface with a Telegram API (if there is one) or with a SMS center without a modem is a a new can of worms.

Answer (score 0):

`logwatch` is the tool to use. You'll probably need to install it, and an Internet search will find tutorials, hints, contributed configurations, ... See https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/logwatch